# CakePHP UnitTest takes too long ~ 37 minutes

Tags: cakephp, ssh, phpunit, fixtures, phpseclib

I am dealing with a CakePHP project. Recently I added UnitTests to the project. My system Configuration is:

- PHPUnit 3.7.24.
- Cake Versio 2.4.2.
- VM Server with a 4 Core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 2.50GHz
- 9.1-RC3 FreeBSD.

But one of my tests is running very slow. It needs ~ 37 minutes to be finished. I am using 10 fixtures in this test but I don't load records them from another database,
thus my Fixture Classes contain only this line:

```
public $import = array('model' => 'Model', 'records' => false);
```

The test contains three testAction()-calls. Two of them run fast, the third one doesn't. The third call runs a controller action which does the following:

- run two find-queries on a tables with ~ 2 entries
- get the webvserver ip with ifconfig
- connect to another vm per ssh (with phpseclib)
- copy a 3,6 MB file with scp from webserver to vm
- run a python script
- copy it's json output back to the webserver
- save the json information in the webserver's database (< 40 table entries)
- remove the python script results on the vm

When I run the same controller action by clicking on an Icon in the webinterface, then it finishes after < 1 mniute. But running it per testAction() within the unit test
takes ~ 37 minutes, as I told.

- I've already tried to set Configure::write('debug', 0);, without any effect.
- I ran the test in the console per "cake test" command, without any performance boost.
- I dereased Model->recursive as much as I could to get all information

Any idea how to fasten this UnitTest? My other UnitTests only take < 1 minute.

Comment: Like Ilie Pandia said, it'd be good to know which part of your script is causing the slow down. Is it the "run two find-queries" or the "get the webvserver ip with ifconfig" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to profile each operation in that test in a log file so you will know where the problem is.

Use PHP's [`microtime()`](https://www.php.net/microtime) function to measure things precisely.

Also it's a very good practice to use log files to monitor what is going on and to get rough estimates of how much operations take. Such a log file will show you immediately where the bottleneck is...

So I recommend you setup logging and if you need precise timing use the `microtime()` function.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Of course this helped me. The problem was that the python script took too long. The script was run on the virtual machine. And this one was limited to 128 MB RAM but the script needed > 750 MB. So the problem wasn't even cake-related nor it was phpseclib-related.

Answer (score -1):

This is **NOT** a unit testing. You are testing network connection, bash (or whatever) interpretator and database. UnitTest **MUST** test only one **unit** of code - usually class. You must not use network or database. If you testing sequience of action class should take - use mock objects and expectations of method class.